# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) - Django & React Web App

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, csrf

Any ideea why I get this error when trying to register an user?

```
# views.py

class SignupView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data

            username = data.get('username')
            email = data.get('email')
            password = data.get('password')
            confirm_password = data.get('confirmPassword')

            if password != confirm_password:
                return Response({'error': 'Passwords do not match'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                return Response({'error': 'Username already exists'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, email=email)
            user_profile.save()

            return Response({'success': 'User created successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

```
"""
# settings.py

Django settings for daweb_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_i9x#yg#qq9!#&uw3e7$86&#w%g1t)%ft@ebfv3$ai*x+%a137'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'RealEstateApp.apps.RealestateappConfig'
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'daweb_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'daweb_project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ]
}

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000']
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

```
//CSRFToken.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const getToken = async () => {
  await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/csrf_token`, { withCredentials: true });
}

const getCookie = (name) => {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (const element of cookies) {
      const cookie = element.trim();
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

const CSRFToken = () => {
  const [csrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    getToken();
    setCsrfToken(getCookie('csrftoken'));
  }, []);


  return (
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value={csrfToken} />
  );
};

export default CSRFToken;
```

```
//API_CALL

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (!formIsValid())
      return

    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/signup`, {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
    }, {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
      },
    })
        .then(() => {
          setSuccess('User created successfully');
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error.response.data.error);
          setSuccess(null);
        });
  }
```

It worsk from postman, and the form also contains an instance of . I don't want to exempt the CSRF token as I need to implement CSRF token & sessions for security. Any ideea what am I doing wrong ? Maybe some settings are not properly configure but it shouldn't work from postman. My guess is that I'm missing something in the frontend code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The CSRF Token also appears in the headers